# Pyspark - date_add based on fixed date and get increment from other column

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I need to add days on date 1960-01-01 to get the real date value. Based on that, I have tried to achieve it doing:

```
df_immigration_new = df_immigration\
    .withColumn('depdate2', F.col('depdate').cast(T.IntegerType()))\
    .withColumn('depdate', F.date_add(F.to_date('1960-01-01'), F.col('depdate2')))\
    .show(n=1, truncate=False)
```

But it throws me an exception: `TypeError: Column is not iterable`.

If I change `F.col('depdate2')` to an Integer value, it works but I'm not sure how to use a column instead of a fixed value.

Comment: try this for 2nd withColumn `.withColumn('depdate', F.expr("""date_add(to_date('1960-01-01'), depdate2)"""))`

Answer (score 1):

Using `F.date_add()` expects the first argument to be a date and the second argument to be an integer denoting the number of days to be added to the date.

You can achieve what you want using a SQL expression:

```
 df.withColumn("new_Date", F.expr("date_add(to_date('1960-01-01'), number_of_days)")).show()
```

Result:

```
+----------+--------------+----------+
|      date|number_of_days|  new_date|
+----------+--------------+----------+
|1960-01-01|             1|1960-01-02|
|1960-01-01|             2|1960-01-03|
+----------+--------------+----------+
```